# automatically stop when a process ends in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to limit the running time for exec.exe to 60 seconds but if exec.exe ends before the timeout will stop automatically. I have tried from various sources but to no avail, I hope anyone can help me. Thanks for all your help.

My batch scripts:

```
@echo off
start S:\sys_\sys_e\exec.exe
timeout /t 60
taskkill /im exec.exe
exit /b 0
```

Comment: What's the problem when your script tries to kill a nonexistent process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply test the process every second to see if it is still running, if it is not stop the `timeout` and `exit`.

```
@echo off & set cnt=
start "" "S:\sys_\sys_e\exec.exe"
:count
(timeout /t 1)>nul
set /a cnt+=1
if %cnt% lss 60 (
   tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq exec.exe" | findstr "exec" >nul && goto :count || exit /b 0
) else (
   taskkill /IM "exec.exe"
)
```

Explanation: We're doing a simple arithmetic addition by one each time we `goto` the label `:count`. We test the count each time to ensure it is not yet 60 seconds, if not, we test if the process is still running using `tasklist` and piping it to `findstr` so we are able to use `errorlevel`

The conditional operators `&&` is saying, if the exit code of the previous command is true, issue the command after `&&` which simply goes back to the label. Then `||` becomes the `or` operator, meaning if the condition is false, run the preceding command, which in this case is `exit`. So should the executable have by stopped, we will detect it and simply stop the script.
However, if the executable is still active ny the time out `%cnt%` variable has reached a count of `60` we will kill it.